# How to save a value of a table into a variable using Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to improve my home automation with the Fibaro HC2.

The building is divided into several sections and I want to create a list of devices with the name of the section. With the Fibaro API I only get the Section ID, but not the name. With json.encode I get the contents of this table:

```
[
   {
      "Id":4,
      "sortOrder":3,
      "name":"basement"
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "sortOrder":2,
      "name":"GROUND FLOOR"
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "sortOrder":4,
      "name":"FIRST FLOOR"
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "sortOrder":1,
      "name":"OUTSIDE"
   }
]
```

sortOrder does not matter. What I have done:

```
local jS = json.encode (sections)
for i = 1, #sections do
    local jS = json.encode (sections [i])
    s = string.gsub (jS, ', "sortOrder":% d', "")
    print (s)
end
```

This is the output:

```
{ "Id": 4, "name": "BASEMENT"}    
{ "Id": 5, "name": "GROUND FLOOR"}    
{ "Id": 6, "name": "FIRST FLOOR"}    
{ "Id": 7, "name": "OUTSIDE"}
```

I have no idea if that makes sense. I would like to have a function that stores the name in a variable:

```
function getSectionNamebyID (secID)
    if secId == "4" then sectionname = "BASEMENT" end
    if secId == "5" then sectionname = "GROUNDFLOOR" end
    --...
    return sectionname
end
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve: "save value of table into variable" – what. Do you intend to lookup the `name` by `Id`, or is it something else? Also, why are you using `json.encode`? Is the data coming in as JSON, or are you just using that to pretty-print the table? If I read it correctly, sections is array-like and looks like `{ { Id = 4, sortOrder = 3, name = "basement" }, … }` – is that correct?

Comment: Some notes on the last code block: (1) If you don't say `local sectionname` inside the function, `sectionname` will be a global variable – don't do that. (2) `if k == x then foo = a elseif k == y then foo = b … end ; return foo` simplifies to `if k == x then return a elseif k == y then return b … end`, and (3) even further: Don't use `if…elseif…elseif`, use a lookup table. `lut = { [x] = a, [y] = b, … }` and just `return lut[k]`. Also, (4) keep track of the types: From the JSON it looks as if `Id` is a number, but your `getSectionByID` checks strings – and `"4" != 4`.

Comment: Thats all right. I need the names. I can produce the same output as in the square brackets with an http request, but that needs a lot more code, that's why I used JSON.
With this code in my script I get the sectionID:
 `local sectionID = fibaro: getSectionID (devices [id])`
That's why I need a function that gives me the corresponding names.

Comment: The last section of the code was just an example and should illustrate what I want to achieve.

My list should look like this:
`No. -section ---------- device name - room --------------------- Bat. status
1) groundfloor -------- RFID Reader- (Toilet) ------------------- 86% OK`
Everything is done except for the section.

I'm sorry that it was not clear. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

A very [nice tutorial](https://forum.fibaro.com/topic/23942-tutorial-using-a-hometable-to-store-device-and-scene-ids/page/6/) on how to read all devices etc. in fibaro and store that table of information as a json string value in a global variable.

The most interesting part is the script which is implemented as a lua scene in fibaro. Just create a global variable with the name "HomeTable" and run the scene manually to store all devices/scenes etc. in one variable:

```
--[[
%% autostart
%% properties
%% events
%% globals
--]]

local debug = true --set to false to stop debug messages

-- HOME TABLE FOR ANYTHING IN ADDITION TO DEVICES, VDs, iOS DEVICES
-- EDIT TO YOUR NEEDS OR KEEP BLANK: jsonHome = {}
jsonHome = {

    scene = {
        HueSceneStart=43,
        AlexaSceneStart=67,
    },

    users = {
        --admin=2,frank=1564,sylvia=1565
    },
}

-- NO USER EDITS NEEDED BELOW

local function log(str) if debug then fibaro:debug(str); end; end 

devices=fibaro:getDevicesId({visible = true, enabled = true}) -- get list of all visible and enabled devices
log("Fill hometable with "..#devices.." devices")

-- FILL THE HOMETABLE WITH ALL VDs, DEVICES AND iOS DEVICES
for k,i in ipairs(devices) do
    deviceName=string.gsub(fibaro:getName(i), "%s+", "") -- eliminate spaces in devicename

    -- Uncomment this to eliminate all non-alphanumeric characters in devicename
    -- deviceName=string.gsub(fibaro:getName(i), "%W", "") 
    
    if fibaro:getType(i) == "virtual_device" then -- Add VDs to Hometable
        if jsonHome.VD == nil then -- Add VD to the table
            jsonHome.VD = {}  
        end
        jsonHome.VD[deviceName]=i
        log("i="..i..", type="..fibaro:getType(i)..", device="..deviceName)
    elseif fibaro:getType(i) == "iOS_device" then -- Add iOS devices to Hometable
        if jsonHome.devices == nil then -- Add iOS devices to the table
            jsonHome.devices = {}  
        end
        jsonHome.devices[deviceName]=i
        log("i="..i..", type="..fibaro:getType(i)..", device="..deviceName)
    else -- Add all other devices to the table
        roomID = fibaro:getRoomID(i)
        if roomID == 0 then
            roomname = "Unallocated"
        else
            roomname=string.gsub(fibaro:getRoomName(roomID), "%s+", "") -- eliminate spaces in roomname
            -- Uncomment this to eliminate all non-alphanumeric characters in roomname
            -- roomname=string.gsub(fibaro:getRoomName(roomID), "%W", "")
        end
        if jsonHome[roomname] == nil then -- Add room to the table
            jsonHome[roomname] = {}  
        end
        jsonHome[roomname][deviceName]=i
        log("i="..i..", type="..fibaro:getType(i)..", device="..deviceName..", room="..roomname)
    end
end

jHomeTable = json.encode(jsonHome)              -- ENCODES THE DATA IN JSON FORMAT BEFORE STORING
fibaro:setGlobal("HomeTable", jHomeTable)       -- THIS STORES THE DATA IN THE VARIABLE
log("global jTable created:")                   -- STANDARD DEBUG LINE TO DISPLAY A MESSAGE
log(jHomeTable)
```

After running it, you can use it by following example. In my case the room name was "Workingroom" and the name of the device was "Shutter":

```
--[[
%% properties
%% events
%% globals
--]]

local ht = json.decode(fibaro:getGlobalValue("HomeTable"))
fibaro:call(ht.Workingroom.Shutter, "open")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this was deliberate or not, but you linked to a particular page of Fibaro's forum, which means the original post is hidden. If you were intending to link to a particular reply, it's not clear which one.